# How do I get passed the switch puzzle in the Evil Spirit Club Floor 2?

Tags: persona-q

In the south east corner of the Evil Spirit Club there are four room with FOE's and switches. I need to press the switches in the correct order. How can I figure out this order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get passed this puzzle you only need to find one clue that is in a dead end pretty close by. It points out the theme you should be looking for and once you understand the theme the puzzle falls into place.

- The clue is found:

> directly to the west of the four rooms (Zone E5(C1 of that zone)). Ken points out that pictured are Dice nets with the 5's and 6's scratched out.

- Using the clue you now know to look for related patterns in those four rooms.
- > If you mark where the FOE's are in the northwest room you will notice that the FOE's are identical to the four face of a normal Die. The room in the southeast are in that of the three face. That only leaves the last two rooms.
- You should be able to find a switch in these rooms:

> at location E6(D4).

- > When you activate the switch the FOE's disappear and the lights turn on. The northeast rooms lights are identical to that of the two face on a die and the southwest room is that of the one face on a die.
- Putting the positions and clues together you now know what order to push the switches in order to open the door.
- > With the lights on since it is impossible to press the switched in the correct order with them off you need to press them in the order, Southwest, Northeast, Southeast and then finally Northwest.

Answer (score -1):

Step on switches in order: Southwest, Northeast, Southeast, Northwest.